# Creating a custom DynamoDBMarshaller in Scala

Tags: java, json, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS DynamoDB in a scala project.  I'd like to write a custom [`DynamoDBMapper`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.ArbitraryDataMapping.html) (also in scala).  It seems that the custom mapper has to be an equivalent of java's `static public class`.

However if I implement it as a scala object; adding the mapping to annotation via:
`@DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = classOf[MyDynamoDBConverter])`

results in error:
`not found: type MyDynamoDBConverter`

`@DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = MyDynamoDBConverter.getClass)`

results in error: `annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: MyDynamoDBConverter.getClass()`

`@DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = classOf[MyDynamoDBConverter.type])`

results in error: `class type required but MyDynamoDBConverter.type found`

Implementing mapper as a class results in a runtime exception:

```
Cannot marshall type class MyCaseClass without a custom marshaler or @DynamoDBDocument annotation.
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Cannot marshall type class MyCaseClass without a custom marshaler or @DynamoDBDocument annotation.
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.getObjectToMapMarshaller(ConversionSchemas.java:390)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.augment(ConversionSchemas.java:319)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.getMarshaller(ConversionSchemas.java:293)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.convert(ConversionSchemas.java:258)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:962)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:824)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:669)
```

Would highly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is `MyDynamoDBConverter` a class (as opposed to an object)? Is it in scope?

Comment: It is in scope.  For `MyDynamoDBConverter` tried it both ways `class` and `object`.  There seems to be a dilemma: as a `class` it doesn't get recognized (since DynamoDB inoker expects java's equivalent of `static public class`);  as an `object` am not able to access it's `class` to configure `@DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass =  ...)`